# PHP Last line in the code is showing error

Tags: php

code is showing error can anyone help me with the problem

```
    $body .= 'Message: ' .echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>"; echo "Name:".$name1; echo "<br>"; echo "Email:".$email1; echo "<br>";
 if(empty($contact)){echo("Contact:Didn't give anything.");} else{ echo "Contact:".$contact; } echo "<br>"; echo "Company:".$company; echo "<br>"; if(empty($aDoor)) { echo("You didn't select anything."); } else { $N = count($aDoor); 
 echo("You selected $N item(s): "); for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++){ echo($aDoor[$i] . " / "); } } echo "<br>"; 
 echo "website:".$website; echo "<br>"; echo "Projectdetail:".$projectdetail; echo "<br>"; if(empty($budget)){ 
 echo("budget:You didn't select anything."); } else { echo "budget:".$budget; } echo "<br>"; echo "budgetother:".$input_9_other;
 . "\n\n";
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

Comment: `echo` is a language construct which sends strings to the output buffer. You're really just looking to append a plain string onto `$body`.

Answer (score 0):

You concat and echo   in this line:

```
$body .= 'Message: ' .echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
```

you are assigning value to a variable so remove echo and take two strings together(append it).

```
  $body .= "Message: <h2>Your Input:</h2>";
```

try this:

```
$body .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['input_1'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['input_11'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['input_12'] . "\n\n";
$body .= "Message: <h2>Your Input:</h2>";
```

Comment: actually i am trying to send a bigger message not just your input so yes this line works but others are causing problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the word `echo`. It's a command to output a string to the webpage, but you're trying to include it in the `$body` string you're building.

The correct fix depends on exactly what you want to achieve. You probably want to just build the string initially (taking out the `echo`):

```
$body .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['input_1'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['input_11'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['input_12'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Message: <h2>Your Input:</h2>';
```

After that, you can output the whole string if you want to:

```
echo $body;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to concatenate a string and echo it halfway through the same statement.

```
$body .= "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
$body .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['input_1'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['input_11'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['input_12'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Message: '; // I'm guessing you'll want another $_POST['input_?'] here
// At the end echo the whole message
echo $body;
```

**Updated Question**

I can't tell if you're trying to echo the text or assign it to a variable so I've guessed echo it.

```
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo "Name: $name1";
echo "<br>Email: $email1";
echo "<br>" . (empty($contact) ? "Contact: Didn't give anything." : "Contact: $contact");
echo "<br>Company: $company";
if (empty($aDoor)) {
  echo "<br>You didn't select anything.";
} else {
  $N = count($aDoor);
  echo "<br>You selected $N item(s): ";
  for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    echo $aDoor[$i] . " / ";
}
echo "<br>Website: $website";
echo "<br>Projectdetail: $projectdetail";
echo "<br>" . (empty($budget) ? "budget: You didn't select anything." : "budget: $budget");
echo "<br>budgetother: $input_9_other";
```

Comment: hello i have changed the message can you help me correct it.Its too complex for me.

Answer (score 0):

Awlad Liton answer is correct, I will just add different ways of doing it (relying on your code); Examples should explain you why you get syntax error there.

```
$body .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['input_1'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['input_11'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['input_12'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Message: ' . "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
```

or

```
$body .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['input_1'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['input_11'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['input_12'] . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Message: ';
echo  "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
```